# Rails: gem install vs git clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047008/rails-gem-install-vs-gemfilebnudle-install) but not the same.

I am new to Rails and even with Ruby usually I only do console utilities to do a very particular things that I need to do.

I would like to learn more about Rails and try out some open source Rails applications. For discussion sake, let's say I would like to setup [Storytime](https://github.com/CultivateLabs/storytime) CMS.

In the installation guide, it says I need to add `gem storytime` to my Gemfile. While I know how to do this and I know this is the equivalent (sort of) to `gem install storytime`, what I don't understand is: What is the different between

1. `gem install storytime`
2. Clone the git repository and run `bundle install`

And further to that, in my current machine, after cloning git repository, running `bundle install` (yes I have bundler gem installed) gave me an error. While `gem install storytime` went successfully.

Also, the guide says "Add Storytime to your Gemfile". If I started from scratch, I don't have Gemfile yet. Is that when I need to do `bundle init` first?

I know this is quite newbie question but I have searched about this and can't get any clear info. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yeah you can do bundle init first or just create a `Gemfile` manually and make sure the first line is `source "http://rubygems.org"`

Comment: So in what situation I would want to clone git repo and run `bundle install`?

Comment: not everyone gets around to packaging their code as a gem, so sometimes you have to. Other times it can be useful to clone the source to make some slight changes, e.g. a fork.

Answer (score 0):

Gems are rubys packaging mechanism. It is a way to distribute packaged ruby code through a centralized service (rubygems.org). Developers can build gems and upload them to rubygems.org so other developers have easy access to the "gemified" source code.

Note: "Centralized" is a simplification: you can setup your own gem-server and use this one instead. This is useful for private gems.

When you do a `git clone` then you download the source code from a Git repository (usually github.com, but can be something different).

You can also have bundler fetch Gems from a git repository. This is convenient, when you need a specific version of the gem that has not been released yet. I.e. the fix for a bug has been commited to the repository but no new version has been released.

So in short, I'd put it like:
Git: where developers work on the code, enhance it
Gem: packaged, snapshot of code